# Usual and "unusual" indeterminate forms

Tags: analysis, indeterminate-forms

I've always read there are seven "main" indeterminate forms, 0/0, ∞/∞,∞−∞,0<sup>∞</sup>,0<sup>0</sup>,1<sup>∞</sup>,∞<sup>0</sup>.

I've recently started working more keenly on analysis, and the seven "main" forms are never expanded to include "unusual" forms. Does anyone know what are they ?

I've read somewhere that things likes lim [sin x + sin x] as x goes to ∞ could be one such indetermination. What do you think ?

All the best,
G.

Comment: What about combinations of forms such as $\dfrac{\infty-\infty}{\infty - \infty}$?  The possibilities are endless.

Comment: Ok, sure. But, as far as I read it, if take a fraction of polynomials and apply *strictly* the rules of limits when x goes to ∞, one could get that; for example, $\frac{x^2-9x}{x^7-8x}$, but then could be solved by simplification or use of other rules. Another question around here was about  (-1)<sup>∞</sup>, that could either be 1 or -1 depending on ∞ being odd or even, but still uses the same symbolism. On the other hand, "sin x + sin x" or "cos x + cos x" use different symbolism and are also indeterminate because they "are" any value between -2 and 2. Or am I being to picky?

Comment: Who said anything about polynomials?